# how to fix,"Call to a member function row() on null "

Tags: codeigniter

How to fix

> Call to a member function row() on null

**THIS IS MY CONTROLLER**

```
function forwardtrack($param='',$param2='') {
if(sizeof($this->db->get_where('st_forward',array('letter_no' =>$param.'/'.$param2))->result_array())>0 && (!($param.'/'.$param2) )){
    $data1['message']= 'notallow';
    $this->load->view('track1',$data1);
}
else{
    $data1['name']=$this->db->get_where('bpas_user_profiles',array('AgencyMainParentID' =>$this->session->userdata('ministryId'),'AgencyParentID'=>$this->session->userdata('parentID'),'AgencyID'=>$this->session->userdata('agencyID')))->result_array();

$data1['userdeatils']=$this->ag->tracks($param.'/'.$param2); 
$this->load->view('userManagement/forward2', $data1);
}

   /* ag=> agency model */


}
```

**THIS IS MY MODEL**

```
public function tracks($letterno="")
{

      $query= $this->db->get_where('st_dak_details',array('dakLetterNo'=>$letterno))->row();
      return $query;
 }
```

**THIS VIEW PAGE**

```
<br/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i>forward to
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#" method="post" id="forwardmessage">


                <div class="form-group">
                   <label  for="letter"class="col-xs-12 col-lg-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1">letter_no: </label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>

                     <?php 


                                foreach($userdeatils->row() as $row): ?>

                     <input name="dakLetterNo" id="dakLetterNo" value="<?php echo $row['dakLetterNo'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                   </div>



                </div>




                <!-- <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">created: </label>
                   <div class="input-group">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="copy_to" id="copy_to" value="<?php //echo $userdeatils->created;?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                   </div>   -->

                   <div class="form-group">

                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 control-label">Attachment: </label>
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> 
                        <input type="file" name="Attachment" id="Attachment">
                   </div>    
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Subject: </label>
                      <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="subjecterr"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="subject" id="Remark" value="<?php echo $row['Remark'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />   

                     </div>          
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Place: </label>
                     <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="place" id="place" value="<?php echo $row['place'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />  
                    </div>


                </div>
                <div class="form-group">

                   <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">from: </label>
                   <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="from" id="receieve_add" value="<?php echo $row['receieve_add'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                  </div>

                </div>

                <div class="form-group">


                     <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Created: </label>
                   <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10">
                     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span>
                     <input name="created" id="created" value="<?php echo $row['created'];?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required />
                   </div>
               </div>

                <!-- </div> -->

                <!-- <div class="form-group"> -->


                     <!-- <label class="col-xs-12 col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Message: </label> -->
                   <!-- <div class="input-group" class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> -->
                     <!-- <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card"></i></span> -->
                     <!-- <input name="message" id="message" value="<?php //echo $userdeatils->created;?>"readonly="true" class="form-control" type="text" required /> -->
                   <!-- </div> -->

                <!-- </div> -->
                 <?php endforeach;?>

                <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">Message: </label>
                   <div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10"> 
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message"></textarea>
                        <span id="messageerr" class="text-danger"></span>
                   </div>    
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
                        Forward to
                    </label>
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                        <select name="forwardto[]" id="agency" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select</option>
                           <?php 
                           foreach($name as $row):  ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $row['cid']?>">
                                <?php echo $row['FirstName'].$row['MiddleName'].$row['LastName']?>
                              </option>
                            <?php endforeach;?>
                        </select> 
                        <span id="forwarderr" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public function tracks($letterno="")
{

      $query= $this->db->get_where('st_dak_details',array('dakLetterNo'=>$letterno));
      if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
      } else {
            return array();
      }
 }
```

Controller:

```
function forwardtrack($param = '', $param2 = '') {
        if (sizeof($this->db->get_where('st_forward', array('letter_no' => $param . '/' . $param2))->result_array()) > 0 && (!($param . '/' . $param2) )) {
            $data1['message'] = 'notallow';
            $this->load->view('track1', $data1);
        } else {
            $data1['name'] = $this->db->get_where('bpas_user_profiles', array('AgencyMainParentID' => $this->session->userdata('ministryId'), 'AgencyParentID' => $this->session->userdata('parentID'), 'AgencyID' => $this->session->userdata('agencyID')))->result_array();
            $data1['userdeatils'] = $this->ag->tracks($param . '/' . $param2);
            $this->load->view('userManagement/forward2', $data1);
        }

        /* ag=> agency model */
}
```

View:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($userdeatils)){
    foreach($userdeatils as $row) { ?>
    //yout html code
    ...
    ...
    <?php } ?>//foreach close
<?php } ?>//if close
```

Comment: ,thanks  for your  solution, it resolved the problem .However  I am trying to pull data from table named ' st_dak_details' by passing two parameters joined as single parameter like  $param . '/' . $param2. suppose I am passing l/49 as parameter but it is not getting populated in view page.. Can you help please.

Comment: You're welcome, Please accept the answer if it works, Yes you can do this with `where_in` if you want to add two conditions in one column